# Build Pipeline for Xamarin project in VSTS

Tags: c#, devops

I am current working on creating a build pipeline for a xamarin project and deploy to app center. I have disabled the other task to troubleshoot the issue. I am currently experiencing the following error please see attached snaps. Help will be appreciated.

[image]

After updating the   in the csproj file for the Droid project as l suspect it was not pointing to the correct path on build. I am now getting the following error.

> [error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(654,2): Error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework "MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.

[image]

Comment: Where is the error? Though _"a picture is worth thousand words"_ here in SO, people prefer lot of descriptions, textual information :-)

Comment: first thing: you didn't attach a snap of an error, and even if you did it would be better as text. second thing: you have configured a .sln in the project-input. you are supposed to configure the path to *.csproj-files in that input field. also you should configure a target

Comment: I apologise for that D.J i missed the snap with the actuaal error l have updated my post with the actual error which is :  imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets"

Comment: I updated the  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" /> in the csproj file and am now getting the following error:  Error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework "MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0" were not found